# Sort by a value from a database table instead of alphabetically

Tags: javascript

In one of my forms, I have a dropdrown with selectable options, that I have sorted  alphabetically (code below). I want to change it to sort it by the value of `level` assigned to it from the same database.

[My database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIvpl.png)

Is there a function like `.valueOf(level)`?

```
var options = $("#practitioner_competence_level_id_create option");
options.detach().sort(function(a,b) {
    var at = $(a).text();
    var bt = $(b).text();
    return (at > bt)?1:((at < bt)?-1:0);
});
options.appendTo("#practitioner_competence_level_id_create");
```

Comment: Put a data attribute on them when you generate them and sort by that attribute value

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by setting the value in  to {{$level->level}} from my database, and then creating sorting script by a level value.

```
<select name="practitioner_competence_level_id_create"
                        id="practitioner_competence_level_id_create"
                        class="form-control">
                    @foreach($competence_levels as $level)
                        <option value="{{$level->level}}">{{$level->name}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
```

Sorting script:

```
var selectList = $('#practitioner_competence_level_id_create option');

selectList.sort(function(a,b){
    a = a.value;
    b = b.value;
    return a-b;
});

$('#practitioner_competence_level_id_create').html(selectList);
```

Answer (score -3):

you can sort them by level using

```
list.sort((a, b) => (a.level > b.level) ? 1 : -1)
```

this will sort the array based on level.

Comment: `<option>` elements have no `level` property